# Getting a long algorithm2e smaller by putting parts of it side by side

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm currently trying to replicate this algorithm in `algorithm2e`:

[image: SIKE jInvariant calculation]
(Taken from https://sike.org/files/SIDH-spec.pdf)

And I'm unable to find out how I can do something similar, as it would save me some valuable space.

I've tried using a table, but it makes everything a single line like so:

[image: not working table layout]

So I am not sure how such an effect could be achieved.

Comment: Could you post your compilable example ?